# Replace a certain string of xml node using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-update

I'd like to replace "~" of  element with the value of  element using xquery (Update facility). Is this possible?

Sample.xml

```
<entry>
<keyword>ace</keyword>
<example>~ card</example>
</entry>
```

Result.xml

```
<entry>
<keyword>ace</keyword>
<example>ace card</example>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Xquery will modify the node value.

```
for $i in /entry
  return replace($i/example, '~', $i/keyword);
```

Now, if you want to update the node with this value, you should let us know with which engine you are running the Xquery.